# JDBC library for inserting data from excel to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to insert data from a excel sheet to mySql db using JDBC. Instead of generating insert/update statements manually , is there any library I can use of?

I have checked multiple libraries like dbUtils,POI and other but unable to find this functionality.

Comment: I have implemented programs that did this (used JExcelAPI to read the Excel file, and the database was either Postgres or Microsoft SQL Server). As I recall, there was a business-specific API built on Hibernate that I used to persist the data. However, a "generic tool" to take specified rows and columns in Excel and INSERT/UPDATE them into a table might be easier to do in perl than Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no magic library that will take a Excel Spreadsheet and place it in a database.

You can create the schema in the database for the data and with [jooq](http://www.jooq.org/) generate a Java representation of the schema. Afterwards you will have to parse the Excel file with something like POI or jXL. Jooq will help you write the inserts and updates in a more Java friendly DSL manner.